# Does probability theory require infinitesimals to work?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, infinitesimals

I'm taking an intro to probability class, and my book lists this as an axiom:

$$P(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P(A_k)$$

where $A_k$ is an event and $P(A_k)$ is the probability of $A_k$.

Now consider the question of picking a random number in an interval. For instance, a random number is picked between 0 and 1. What's the probability of picking 0.5?

I see two possible answers:

1) 0: If it's 0, then you get weird results. For instance, say you pick a random number between 0 and 1. What's the probability of the number being less than 0.5? Well using the axiom at the very top, the probability of this is the sum of the probabilities of picking each number less than 0.5. Since they are all 0, the probability of picking a number less than 0.5 is 0. Which is obviously not true.

2) Infinitesimals. This would give you a result I'm assuming would make sense

So the way I see it, probability for continuous sample spaces cannot exist without infinitesimals.

Am I misunderstanding something or can probability for continuous sample spaces not exist without infinitesimals?

Comment: The axiom is for th union of a countable number of (pairwise disjoint) sets. You are misunderstanding the axiom if you interpret it as applying to unions of an uncountable number of sets. There has been some work done on probability from the viewpoint of non-standard analysis. But non-standard analysis is definitely not *needed*.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Hmm, my book doesn't say anything about the set having to be countable. It just lists the theorem.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Also, how can all the samples in a sample space have 0 probability?

Comment: The individual $A_k$ need not be countable. However, the **indices** $k$ run over the natural numbers. So there are only countably many $A_k$.

Comment: For certain probability distributions, over some sample spaces, the probability assigned to any individual element is indeed $0$. This is the case for all the familiar continuous distributions. Probability $0$ does not mean impossible.

Comment: @AndréNicolas But then how can we differentiate between events that are *really* impossible (i.e. a number picked between 0 and 1 being 2) and events that are intuitively just infinitesimals (ti.e. a number picked between 0 and 1 being 0.5)? Surely, it's important to differentiate between the two concepts?

Comment: One can differentiate. If $X$ has uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, then the event $X=17$ is impossible, while the event $X=0.3$ is not. Quite clear. Each event has probability $0$, so the probability concept is insufficient to differentiate between the two.

Comment: @AndréNicolas So you're telling me it's not possible to differentiate between the events with probability? It seems a bit weird to me that probability can't differentiate between impossible and possible events...

Comment: The probability *measure* does not differentiate. I do not think of that as weird.  Analogously, the concept of cardinality does not differentiate between the sizes of the set of natural numbers and the set of even natural numbers.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I'm sure it makes sense mathematically, but its very unintuitive.

Comment: After a while it will seem intuitively reasonable. Take $X$ with continuous uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. The probability $X$ is between $0.49$ and $0.51$ is $0.02$. The probability it is between $0.499$ and $0.501$ is $0.002$. And so on. So if we wish to assign a real number to the probability that $X$ is exactly $0.5$, we must assign the number $0$. Remember that probability *models* for physical situations are just that, *mathematical models*. They do not need to fit exactly to be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a uniform distribution on an interval, the probability of occurrence of any one point is 0.  There is no need for infintessimals.  Results you get are internally consistent.  The probability of occurrence in any interval is proportional to the length of that interval.

Comment: But if the probability is 0, then using the axiom I listed above, can't you show that the probability of a random number between 0 and 1 being less than 0.5 is 0?

Comment: Also, how can all the samples in a sample space have zero probability?

Comment: @pdfgdfg The key is the countability. While each point separately has probability zero, $[0,1]$ is not a countable union of single points (i.e. it is uncountable). So there is no difficulty. One way of viewing the zero probability aspect is in a frequentist description: typically, whatever your (say) first value in an infinite sequence of random numbers is, you will only see it that one time. Thus the fraction of times that it appeared will converge to zero. To a frequentist, this is the meaning of "probability".

Comment: @Ian Hmm, that's hard to wrap my mind around, even with the frequentist explanation. The probability of something being 0 but still happening after an infinite number of times.

Comment: @Ian Also, how do you differentiate between something than happens 0 times after infinite trials ("really 0") and something than happens a finite number of times after infinite trials (a 0 that's intuitively an infinitesimal)?

Comment: @pdfgdfg it has a probability $0$, which means that with probability $1$, this event wont occur. in continuous prob. spaces, there is a differentiation between surely and almost surely. So an event which has a probability $0$, can occur but it wont occur almost surely. It you try it infinitely often, then you will get a certain probability $>0$ of occurence.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören I suppose I'm having trouble understanding why it's okay to map both events that will "almost surely not occur" and "surely not occur" to 0. I mean they are fundamentally very different, so how can we just ignore the difference?

Comment: @pdfgdfg we do not ignore the difference. If all events surely wont occur, the sum of the probabilities of uncountably many of these events will add up to $0$. If the events almost surely wont occur, then the sum of the probabilities of uncountably many of these events will add up to some positive probability.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören "If the events almost surely wont occur, then the sum of the probabilities of uncountably many of these events will add up to some positive probability. " Which theorem is this? An infinite sum of 0s doesn't add up to a positive probability, neither does an integral. Sorry, I'm not trying to be difficult, I'm just confused.

Comment: @pdfgdfg When you add up the probabilities of each singleton in the unit interval, you are taking an uncountable sum of infinitesimal numbers. In standard analysis, this is not a precise statement, and is made precise using integration. ($f(x_i) \Delta x$ is a very small number while $N$ (the number of terms) is a very large number; so you have a sum of a large number of small terms, which adds up to a nonzero, finite amount in the limit.)  In nonstandard analysis, you do exactly what I actually said.

Comment: @Ian 
But even if you add up an *infinite* number of 0s, you still get 0. My point is that the only way to get a finite value for an interval is for the infinitesimal numbers in the interval to have infinitesimal probabilities. I don't see how integration makes it rigorous. How does integration allow you to go from 0 (not an infinitesimal, a hard 0) to a finite amount?

Comment: @pdfgdfg With a $U(0,1)$ random variable, the probability to see a value in $[a,b] \subset (0,1)$ is $\int_a^b dx$. When $a=b$ this is $\int_a^a dx = 0$. That's all we're really saying, when it comes down to it.

Comment: @Ian Oh I see, you writing it as an integral makes a lot more sense to me. I think I get it now! Thanks Ian!